# Python TypeError on executing weather service code

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am using a weather API to design a slack bot service using python.

My source code is-

```
import requests
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def weather(cityname):
    cityid = extractid(cityname)
    url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=" + str(cityid) + "&APPID=c72f730d08a4ea1d121c8e25da7e4411"
    while True:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
        while r.status_code is not requests.codes.ok:
            r = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
        data = ("City: " + soup.city["name"] + ", Country: " + soup.country.text + "\nTemperature: " + soup.temperature["value"] +
    " Celsius\nWind: " + soup.speed["name"] + ", Direction: " + soup.direction["name"] + "\n\n" + soup.weather["value"])
    # print data
    return data


def extractid(cname):
    with open('/home/sourav/Git-Github/fabulous/fabulous/services/city.list.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    for item in data:
        if item["name"] == cname:
            return item["id"]


def on_message(msg, server):
    text = msg.get("text", "")
    match = re.findall(r"~weather (.*)", text)
    if not match:
        return
    searchterm = match[0]
    return weather(searchterm.encode("utf8"))


on_bot_message = on_message
```

But executing the code gives the following error-

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabulous-0.0.1-py2.7.egg/fabulous/services/weather.py", line 19, in weather
" Celsius\nWind: " + soup.speed["name"] + ", Direction: " + soup.direction["name"] + "\n\n" + soup.weather["value"])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I can't figure out what's the error. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

`__getitem__` is called when you ask for dictionary key like `a['abc']` translates to `a.__getitem__('abc')`

so in this case one attribute of `soup` is `None` (`speed`, `direction` or `weather`)

ensure that your r.text contains data you want, simply print it:

```
print(r.text)
```

list structure in parsed data:

```
for child in soup.findChildren():
    print child
```

always assume your entry data might be wrong, instead doing `soup.city` do `soup.find('city')`, it might be empty so:

```
city = soup.find('city')
if len(city):
   city_name = city[0]['name']
else:
   city_name = 'Error' # or empty, or sth
```

Comment: What to do in that case... I'm a beginner and can't figure this out

Comment: Updated answer, debug your inputs, print soup parsed data, etc